Default permissions for partitions at mount with Dolphin - why are there differences?
I read
[https://askubuntu.com/questions/392154/why-are-the-default-permissions-for-media-username-rootroot][1]
and [https://askubuntu.com/questions/257659/why-does-ubuntu-apply-separate-permissions-to-partitions-mounted-with-the-same-p][2]
I have a drive with 3 partions for data, /dev/sdb. All three show in Dolphin, and all can be clicked and thereby mounted.
/media/me$ ls -l
total 136
drwxrwxrwx  1 me me 131072 oct 30 16:09 GFCloud
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root      4096 oct 30 15:55 MyCloud
drwxr-xr-x 23 me me   4096 oct 30 16:09 MyHome

Strange enough, 2 are in my name, one belongs to root, so I have no write access. I know that I could do some chown command or so. But I rather understand where this comes from. It can't be through the folders, because they disappear at an unmounted state. When I unmount all three partitions, it looks like
/media/me$ ls -l
total 0

And when click in Dolphin again, the same happens again.
I would like to understand, why! /etc/fstab says nothing about these partitions.
I should add that I am sitting on 24.04.1
